# ¿Cómo mostrar un listview dentro de una ventana modal bootstrap?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, modal, listview

Lo del modal yo se como colocarlo todo.El listview me funciona a la perfección,pero el modo en que sale en la pagina no me agrada del todo.Es algo poco estético en cuanto a la forma en que se proyecta.Quisiera saber como hacerlo que al presionar un boton asp.net entonces me salga el modal(bootstrap)con el listview con los resultados de la búsqueda realizada.¿Que debo hacer para cuando presione el botón "buscar" se abra el modal y me salga el listview con los datos de la consulta?

Este es el código del botón buscar:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnbuscar" runat="server" Text="Buscar" OnClick="btnbuscar_Click"    />
```

Este es mi listview

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Codigo" >

                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <div class="hola">


                                       <div class="contenedorfoto"> 
                               <asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("Codigo") %>' 
     Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
      </div>
                               <div class="contenedorinfo">
                                   <h3><%# Eval("Marca") %></h3>
                                    <h4><%# Eval("Modelo") %></h4>
                                   <h4><%# Eval("Subnombre") %></h4>
                                   <h4><%# Eval("Año") %></h4>
                                   <h4><%# Eval("Color") %></h4>
                               </div>

                               <div class="contenedorbtndetalle">
                                   <h2><%# Eval("Precioxdia") %></h2>
                                  <a href="DetailsCustomer.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Codigo") %>">Ver detalles</a>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:ListView>
```

Este es el codigo HTML del modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      Modal body..
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo de mi archivo .aspx.cs:

```
protected void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        try
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos WHERE Marca like '" + DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%'" +
                          "AND Tipo like '" + DropDownListTipo.SelectedItem.Text + "%' ", conn);


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            ListView1.DataSource = dt;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```